# How to call google recaptcha code on submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(":submit").click(function(){

var onloadCallback = function() {
    $( "#submitlogin" ).each(function() {
        grecaptcha.render($( this ).attr('id'), {
            'sitekey' : '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
            'callback' : onsubmitlogin
        });
    });

     $( "#submitsignup" ).each(function() {
        grecaptcha.render($( this ).attr('id'), {
            'sitekey' : '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
            'callback' : onsubmitsignup
        });
    });

    $( "#submitforgotpass" ).each(function() {
        grecaptcha.render($( this ).attr('id'), {
            'sitekey' : '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
            'callback' : onsubmitforgotpass
        });
    });


};
});
});
```

I want to load `onloadcallback` function, only when `submit` button is clicked.

But seems like the code inside it, never gets called. What's the problem?

If the problem is not in this code, then let me know, I will update my answer with more code from my original website

Comment: And never make your google key visible to others. Change that before posting questions

Comment: It is not secret key @Sindhoor People can see it in source code anyway, i guess???

Answer (score 0):

You defined `onloadcallback` but never called it when button is clicked. This will work:

```
// Define callback function
var onloadCallback = function() {
  $("#submitlogin").each(function() {
    grecaptcha.render($(this).attr('id'), {
      'sitekey': '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
      'callback': onsubmitlogin
    });
  });

  $("#submitsignup").each(function() {
    grecaptcha.render($(this).attr('id'), {
      'sitekey': '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
      'callback': onsubmitsignup
    });
  });

  $("#submitforgotpass").each(function() {
    grecaptcha.render($(this).attr('id'), {
      'sitekey': '6Lcjvi4UAAAAAIR7_ckItF2HfMEFHx427WUDdGDk',
      'callback': onsubmitforgotpass
    });
  });
};

// Use onloadCallback as event handler
$(":submit").click(onloadCallback);
```

Comment: The code gets loaded with the page load. I want the code to load only on click.

Comment: @Toby you need to define function first and then use it as event handler. it doesn't initialise recapchas until you click.

Comment: I mean, I saw network tab. And google load images when the page is loading. I want google to load images only when submit button is clicked.